# Simple kony.net.httpRequest not working

Tags: javascript, temenos-quantum

I'm unable to connect to any server using the kony.net.httpRequest protocol below.  I always get a statusText of "server error".

```
function test(){
var xmlhttp = new kony.net.HttpRequest();
var url = "http://httpbin.org/get";
xmlhttp.open(constants.HTTP_METHOD_GET, url);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onReadyStateChange = function(){ sunsetCallback(xmlhttp) };
return;
}
function sunsetCallback(xmlhttp){
alert(xmlhttp.statusText);
if (xmlhttp.responseType==constants.HTTP_RESPONSE_TYPE_DOCUMENT){
    sunrise.lblSunrise.text=xmlhttp.response;
}
sunrise.lblSunset.text="ayy lmao";
xmlhttp.suspend();
return;
}
```

Any help welcome!  (I have tried putting the onReadyStateChange line above and below the open, but regardless the sunsetCallback function does execute.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that iOS no longer allows apps to send get requests without editing the plist.  When I changed the request to https and added the App Transport Security Settings dictionary to the plist, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to check the status of the request before doing any operation with the response. You can perform operation once the status is **constants.HTTP_READY_STATE_DONE.**

Please check the working code below:

```
function searchData(){
  srchKey = frmMain.txtData.text;
  var request = new kony.net.HttpRequest();
  request.onReadyStateChange=httpCallbackHandler;
  request.open(constants.HTTP_METHOD_GET, "http://yoururlorapi.com/search/"+srchKey);
  request.setRequestHeader("x-header-appsecret",appsec); //Our own data
  request.send();
}

function httpCallbackHandler(){
  if(this.readyState == constants.HTTP_READY_STATE_DONE){     
    //alert(JSON.stringify(this.response));
    frmSearchRes.segRes.setData(this.response.searchInfo);
    frmSearchRes.show();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!